# How do I know when a woodland mansion is really safe?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I started clearing out a mansion a little while ago and now I’m doing some landscaping to make it my own.  However, every now and then I’ll see a random vex or two flying around.  I always kill them, but does this mean there’s an evoker still hiding somewhere?  I’ve cleared and lit every room, I patrol regularly, and I’m 99.9% sure there are no undiscovered rooms.  Could he be underground nearby?

I’m on legacy console edition if that helps.  Thank you to anyone who reads this.

Comment: Hi Jane E. There are also rooms inside a woodland mansion that are not usually accessible - You will have to break through walls to access them. Vex spawning means that yes, there is an evoker inside somewhere. Your question is also a bit hard to understand - "safe" is quite a vague term. Check out (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on writing questions

Comment: @Jayden If you're sure about your statements, then that would be enough for an answer. In MCJava, it would definitely be correct.

Comment: Can you try putting the difficulty to peaceful? If you cannot do it in-game, then save and exit to the title, navigate to the world, then set the difficulty to peaceful...

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! I appreciate it! And sorry for any confusion, I’m new to this forum.

Comment: Does that mean you solved it? If so, please post your answer for others to see. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/